# Font rendering and :before in firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, zurb-foundation

Hello stackoverflowers,

I have built a site that looks great in Chrome and FF (but only in local server).  When uploaded, chrome does a great job and looks great.  FF does not render the @font-face font..cant figure out why.  Using Foundation 3.

SASS:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'oswald';
src: url('/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.eot');
src: url('/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.svg#oswaldregular') format('svg');
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: lighter;
}

$headerFontFamily: "oswald", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
```

In the footer, there are some social links. these have icons using the a:before pseudo selector.  Again, fine in chrome but no go in firefox.  I have checked the code letter by letter and cant see any typos....but then it is getting late. This one is strange as one of the links is fine, just not the first two:

css:

```
li:nth-of-type(1) a:before {        content: url('../images/watch-trailer.png');            }
        li:nth-of-type(2) a:before {        content: url('../images/rating.png');                   }
        li:nth-of-type(3) a:before {        content: url('../images/book-seats.png');               }
        li:nth-of-type(1) a:hover:before {  content: url('../images/watch-trailer-active.png');     }
        li:nth-of-type(2) a:hover:before {  content: url('../images/rating-active.png');            }
        li:nth-of-type(3) a:hover:before {  content: url('../images/book-seats-active.png');    

}
```

http://schwack.madmantis.co.uk/

Any help with these two questions please.
On a side note, the page does have some problems in ie (such as slider content missing, movie thumb overlay not going transparent and probably a few others) I am not in a big hurry to fix these but would be nice if someone happened to have a fix for them.  Silly IE getting in the way of progress.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is wrongly configured and can't handle font files (woff, svg, eot, ttf).

The server returns a `500 Internal Server Error`.

http://schwack.madmantis.co.uk/stylesheets/font/Oswald/oswald-webfont.woff
http://schwack.madmantis.co.uk/stylesheets/font/Oswald/oswald-webfont.ttf

**Update**

It seems that the fonts are available under (all lowercase) `http://schwack.madmantis.co.uk/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.{format}`

Change your `styles.css` with the following font definition:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'oswald';
  src: url("/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.eot");
  src: url("/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), url("/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.woff") format("woff"), url("/stylesheets/font/Oswald/oswald-webfont.ttf") format("truetype"), url("/stylesheets/font/Oswald/oswald-webfont.svg#oswaldregular") format("svg");
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-style: lighter;
}
```

Comment: humm...it could well be. But why then doesn't the browser default to one of the other many files?  I thought that was the point of fallbacks...

Also, I had literally just changed the folder "Oswald" to "oswald" thinking it might be something silly like that. 

Seems I dont have the joy of knowing it is a miss configuration (404?)
http://schwack.madmantis.co.uk/stylesheets/font/oswald/oswald-webfont.woff

Comment: also, just checked permissions, they were off but after a 755 I didnt notice a change.

Comment: Could your also update the include in your `styles.css` and rename Oswald (capital letter) to oswald (lowercase). The browser does a fallback to `Helvetica` and in my case on `Arial` (because I'm on Windows machine)